# Can someone verify my EL wire oscillator?

Tags: arduino, oscillator, triac, el-wire

I'm pretty new to electronics, but my latest project is a circuit with two "frames" of animation that I make out of EL wire, and I want to build a circuit to switch between them every 2-3 seconds or so.

To do this, I'm wiring an astable multivibrator to 2 triacs which each connect to EL wire strands 1 and 2. My goal is that when the respective square wave goes high, the base of the triac will go high and allow the inverter's AC voltage to pass through to the EL wire.

[image: Here's the circuit diagram]

Can anyone verify that what I'm doing is reasonable? And any tips as I pick out components?

Thanks much!

Comment: It has some problems. What are you trying to accomplish with the switch?

Comment: the goal is for position 1 to always light up EL wire strand #1 and never to light up #2. so it freezes it in the first frame. when it's moved to position two, I want it to alternate between #1 and #2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fairly close to your concept. D1, D2 and the ground symbol are only there to allow it to simulate (don't put them in the real circuit). SW1 is also there for simulation (to make the oscillator start) but it could be your SPST control switch- closed power triac 1 only is 'on' and open is for oscillation. I've shown a 6V supply to keep the reverse Vbe on the transistors acceptable.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBT96C.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This circuit (with 470 ohm resistors) puts about 10mA through the triac gates, so you need to pick triacs that will reliably trigger with 10mA in quadrants II and III (IV is the hard one, and we're not using it).

C1 and C2 can be aluminum electrolytic capacitors rated at 25V or higher.

The main problem with your circuit is insufficient gate current for the triacs, also the time constant is too short for the times you said you wanted, and the 40K resistors are a little high for the required base current.

Comment: thanks so much! I'm now seeing on the datasheet that there's a minimum current to trigger the gates -- really glad that I had you point that out! about the cycle times, [this](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/waveforms/astable.html) says that it's 0.69 * R * C, so isn't that 10.35 seconds for this circuit?

Comment: Using your formula, the period T = 2 * 0.69 * R * C is 2.07 seconds here. R = 15K, C = 100uF.